# Hello world using android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

i'm try to write first native android application and get follow Error
[image]
There are solution package explorer photo and source code for each of changed file:
[image]
[image]
package ua.org.groupab;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProjActivity extends Activity {

```
static {

    System.loadLibrary("ndkfoo");

  }
private native String invokeNativeFunction();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String hello = invokeNativeFunction();
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(hello).show();
}
```

}

What's wrong in me code?
Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ndkfoo.c in the function declaration, it will be valid if the package name in the function  must match with your package name

change the declaration in ndkfoo.c into

```
jstring Java_ua_org_groupab_ProjActivity_invokeNativeFunction()
 {
 }
```

Comment: I change it, but it still not work. I get the same Error? Could you discribe this more detaile? Should i use cygwin after change in ndkfoo.c file or not?